# Break causing runtime error

Tags: c, linked-list, break

I am trying to write a simple program to insert a node in a linked list. Here is how it looks:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
}Node;

void insert (Node **head, int data, int pos)
{
    Node *left, *right, *newNode;
    newNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    int i;

    newNode->data = data;
    right = *head;
    if (pos == 0)
    {
        newNode->next = right;
        *head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = 0; i<pos; i++)
        {
            left = right;
            right = right->next;
            if (right->next == NULL)
            {
               //break; 
            }
        }
        if (i == pos)
        {
            left->next = newNode;
            newNode->next = right;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Cannot insert at the given position");
        }
    }
}

void printLinkedList (Node *head)
{
    while(head != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\t", head->data);
        head = head->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
    Node *head = NULL;
    insert(&head, 1, 0);
    printLinkedList(head);
    //insert(&head, 2, 5);
    //printLinkedList(head);
    insert(&head, 2, 1);
    printLinkedList(head);
    insert(&head, 3, 1);
    printLinkedList(head);
    insert(&head, 4, 3);
    printLinkedList(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine with this except for the break statement in the if (right->next == NULL) loop. I want to add this so if the input position is a value greater than the length of the linked list, then I just break and print that we cannot insert a node at that given position.
But somehow this break statement gives me a runtime error.

What I am doing wrong here?

Edit: Thanks for the inputs
This fixed it:

```
for (i = 0; i<pos; i++)
{
    if (right == NULL)
    {
        break; 
    }
    left = right;
    right = right->next;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not the break that's crashing. It's the `if (right->next == NULL)` that's crashing. The only reason that removing the break makes it not crash is that the compiler then removes the empty if block. The reason that if statement is crashing is that right is NULL, so it's not legal to dereference it.

The root cause of the problem is that you check right->next immediately after doing right = right->next, so you essentially skip over every other element.

Comment: I tried adding this:
if (right->next == NULL)
{
    notFound = 1;
}

}
if (notFound)
        {
            left->next = newNode;
            newNode->next = right;
        }
Things still work...
I do see a case when right could be NULL (Maybe when I am trying to insert in an empty linked list with a position that is not 0) but with my current example in main.c, it should ideally break before right becomes NULL

Answer (score 1):

```
If(right==NULL)
```

Instead

```
If(right->next==NULL)
```

This should work. Since you have already moved the right pointer to the next, the right pointer may be NULL.

Or better

```
left = right;
If(right->next == NULL)
    break;
right = right->next;
```